# Как именно работает метод read() у InputStream?

Tags: java, io

Как же все-таки устроена работа метода `read()`:

1. Почему метод возвращает `int` а не `byte`?
2. Почему возвращается `byte` как `int` в диапазоне от 0 до 255?
3. Почему метод не может возвращать `byte`?
4. Что вернет метод если он считает -1 из входного потока?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

#### Почему метод `read` класса `InputStream` возвращает `int`, а не `byte`

Попробуйте выполнить такой код:

```java
byte myByte = -3; // 11111101

byte[] myArray = {myByte};
InputStream in = new ByteArrayInputStream(myArray);

int myInt = in.read();
System.out.println(myInt); // 253
```

В консоль выводится **253**, а не **-3**.

Почему так происходит?

Тип данных **int** в **Java** является [дополненнным до двух](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%94%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4) целым числом и использует 32 бита вместо 8.

В 32х битном виде число 253 будет:

```
00000000000000000000000011111101
```

т. е. метод **read()** возвращает не само значение **byte**, а его представление в 32х битном виде.

---

#### Как хранятся значения в `int` в `byte`

```
| число | 32 bit                           |   8 bit  |
  -----   --------------------------------   --------
|   . . |  . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . |
|   . . |  . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . |
|  -128 | 11111111111111111111111110000000 | 10000000 |
|  -127 | 11111111111111111111111110000001 | 10000001 |
|  -126 | 11111111111111111111111110000010 | 10000010 |
|  -125 | 11111111111111111111111110000011 | 10000011 |
|   . . |  . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . |  . . . . |
|   . . |  . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . |  . . . . |
|    -2 | 11111111111111111111111111111110 | 11111110 |
|    -1 | 11111111111111111111111111111111 | 11111111 |
|     0 | 00000000000000000000000000000000 | 00000000 |
|     1 | 00000000000000000000000000000001 | 00000001 |
|     2 | 00000000000000000000000000000010 | 00000010 |
|   . . |  . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . |  . . . . |
|   . . |  . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . |  . . . . |
|   125 | 00000000000000000000000001111101 | 01111101 |
|   126 | 00000000000000000000000001111110 | 01111110 |
|   127 | 00000000000000000000000001111111 | 01111111 |
|   . . |  . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . |
|   . . |  . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . |
```

Диапазон **byte** в **Java** лежит от -128 до 127, а возвращаемое значение метода **read()** лежит в диапазоне от 0 до 255.

---

#### Что происходит с числом `byte` в методе `read`

Чтобы получить представление **byte** в **int** в методе **read()** используется [побитовое «И»](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%91%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B5_%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8#%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B5_%C2%AB%D0%98%C2%BB_(AND)) c числом 255, т. е. убираем лидирующие единицы.

```
| число | 32 bit                           |
  -----   --------------------------------
|    -3 | 11111111111111111111111111111101 |
 И
|   255 | 00000000000000000000000011111111 |
 =
|   253 | 00000000000000000000000011111101 |
```

Чтобы из представления получить обратно значение **byte** в **int**, нужно выполнить обратную операцию [побитовое «ИЛИ»](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%91%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B5_%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8#%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B5_%C2%AB%D0%98%D0%9B%D0%98%C2%BB_(OR)) c числом -256, т. е. добавляем лидирующие единицы.

```
| число | 32 bit                           |
  -----   --------------------------------
|   253 | 00000000000000000000000011111101 |
 ИЛИ
|  -256 | 11111111111111111111111100000000 |
 =
|    -3 | 11111111111111111111111111111101 |
```

---

#### Что происходит с числом `byte == -1` в методе `read()`

То же самое: убираем лидирующие единицы.

```
| число | 32 bit                           |
  -----   --------------------------------
|    -1 | 11111111111111111111111111111111 |
 И
|   255 | 00000000000000000000000011111111 |
 =
|   255 | 00000000000000000000000011111111 |
```

Comment: Спасибо, классные ответы, но я несовсем разобрался... что будет если read прочтет -1 из потока? Он сделает побитовое И с 255, потом обратно ИЛИ с -256? Что в итоге? Получается int-овое представление будет совершенно другим? Как получить значение -1?

Comment: Если в методе read встречается byte со значением -1 то он вернет 255? В чем секрет? Как с этим работать?)

Answer (score 7):

На все 4 вопроса вообще один ответ. Возвращается `int` потому что надо такой тип, который может вместить в себя один байт (реальные данные) плюс одно служебное значение (это тот самый `-1`), которое является признаком окончания чтения.

Вообще конечно можно бы было спроектировать метод [read()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html#read()) так, чтобы он возвращал `byte`. Но тогда этот метод в случае окончания потока либо должен был бросать исключение, либо вводить допольнительный метод, при помощи которого бы можно было проверять окончание потока. С обоими способами бы были проблемы, т.к. с исключениями у программистов **всегда** бы оно ловилось, а природа исключений немного другая. А с дополнительным методом нельзя заставить обязать программиста его везде вызывать (ведь если этот вызов будет опущен, то как отделить, когда из потока методом `read` возращается `0` с данными от `0` когда данных нет.

Вообще говоря, этот метод редко используется, в основном из-за своих проблем с производительностью. Предпочтение отдаётся методу [read(byte[])](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html#read(byte[])), который читает сразу массив байт.

P.S. Другой вопрос почему тут выбрали `int`, а не `short`. Точных причин сказать не могу, но скорее потому, что `short` считается *неполноценным* братом `int`. Многие арифметические алгоритмы предпочитают использовать всегда `int`, даже когда точно известно, что диапазона `short` вполне хватит. И ещё есть момент с `short`. JVM-инструкции более заточены на `int`, нежели на `short`.